# c++ pointer error when accessing a member function

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator

Given a vector of classX

```
vector<classX *> myVec;
```

and the following function

```
size_t position_to_index(classY const& p) const{
    double dist = 10;
    size_t i(0);
    for (auto const& element : myVec) {
        classY s = element->position();
        double d = distance(s, p);
        if (d < dist) {
            dist = d;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

the functions distance ans position are defined as follow:

```
double distance(classY const& x1, classY const& x2) {
    return sqrt(pow(x1.x() - x2.x(), 2) + pow(x1.y() - x2.y(), 2));
}

classY position() const {
    return position_;
}
```

if I create a main function to test position_to_index, I get a bunch of 25 error. the first three are:

```
Error   1   error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of 'classY'  file: xutility, line 371.
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator_category'   file: xutility, line 371.
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   file: xutility, line 371.
```

can you please tell me where the problem is, and how to solve it ?

Comment: What line number is the error for? Show that line. There's no iterator_category in the code snipped you posted

Comment: Instead of posting the error list, have a look at the actual compiler output, it will oftentimes have more information.

Comment: I do not get a line number of my cpp file where the problem is. All error are pointing to some cpp library file called xutility as shown in the errors I mentionned.
I think the problem is in that line:
 `classY s = element->position();`

Comment: @GambaOsaca "file: xutility, line 371."

Comment: What's the relationship between classX and classY? And why is position() defined as a function and not as a method of classY?

Comment: Ok, in VS2013 that are the error I got. when using an online compiler I got the follwing error: `prog.cpp:112:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘distance(classY cont&, classY cont&)’
    auto d = distance(s , p);`

Comment: You're likely calling std::distance instead of your distance function. I bet you've got a using std:: in your code, don't you?

Comment: @WillKrause , No I did not.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You are declaring a classX, a classY, a function, calling a method, pasting error messages which have nothing to do with your classes and then editing it to match what you have written. Please paste some real code.

Comment: What is the relationship between `classX` and `classY`?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The solution is that I should have declared the function distance or at least its prototype before using it. I am comming from a python & Matlab backgrounds where the order of declaration doesn't matter, that's why I committed this error and confused all of you. Sorry.

Comment: one more reason for this bunch of errors is that the compiler thought I am using the standar `distance` function even if I did not do `std::distance`. When I changed the name of the function to `distancce`it compiled fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I should have declared the function `distance` or at least its prototype before using it.